# Inserting a formula within a file reference in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I can't really give out the file names which is why I've used the fillers. So my current workbook is called 'thisfile.xls' (again, filler) with 6 columns. B has the dates, and C,D,E,F,G has the values that need to be filled in from values in different files located in 'Z\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3'. A new file is created every day in the format: 'filename_des_Part II_04-03-2017.xls'. The 'filename', 'des', and 'Part II' part remain the same for each new file created but the date part changes everyday (based on whatever day it is). I need 5 separate values from each of these files (they're always located in the same place in each file) and the values are spread out in different worksheets.

Now, in my original file 'thisfile.xls', if B2: 04/03/2017, then I want C2:='Z:Folder1\Folder2\Folder3[filename_des_04-03-2017.xls]Sheet3'!$K$10.

And if B3: 04/04/2017, then I want C3:= 'Z:Folder1\Folder2\Folder3[filename_des_04-04-2017.xls]Sheet3'!$K$10.

So only the date component of the file name would be changing so that I can use autofill and drag the formula down to all the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDIRECT will do this for you. The function is built to do precisely this -- when you need to refer to a cell, but the cell (or workbook) you want to refer to varies based on some other thing. If

Try, in C2,:

```
=INDIRECT("'Z:Folder1\Folder2\Folder3[filename_des_"&TEXT(B2,"DD-MM-YYYY")&".xls]Sheet3'!$K$10")
```

Not sure whether you're using DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY, if the latter instead of the former, just change the DD-MM around in the formula.

Comment: Am I supposed to leave out the filename_des after \Folder3? Or did you just forget to put it in there?

Comment: I just forgot it, apologies, thanks for seeing that. Have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Note: [target book must be open](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). Don't know if that is expected.